# Defining a function with this if statement

Tags: javascript, function

Not sure if I'm doing this right so hopefully someone can help. I have to define an 'explode' function that takes in a string and adds a space around all letters except the first and last. For instance, calling the function with the string `Kristopher` would return `K r i s t o p h e r`.

Here is my code:

```js
function explode(text) {
  var spacedString = '';
  var max = text.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    spacedString += text[i];
    if (i !== (max - 1)) {
      spacedString += ' ';
    }
  }

  return spacedString;
}

console.log(explode('Kristopher'));
```

and it gives me back `kristopher`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your function seems like it should just be `return text.split("").join(" ");`...

Answer (score 1):

Your function is fine, but you can simplify it:

```
function explode(text) {
  return text.split('').join(' ')
}
```

Your `if` statment is wrong, try:

```
if (explode('Kristopher') === 'K r i s t o p h e r') {

   console.log('Success!');

};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a prototype to the `String` object and split the string and return a joined string with spaces.

```js
String.prototype.explode = function () {
    return this.split('').join(' ');
}

console.log('weltschmerz'.explode());
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't calling your `explode` function with `'Kristopher'` passed as the argument. It needs to be

```
if (explode('Kristopher') === 'K r i s t o p h e r') {

   console.log('Success!');

};
```

```js
function explode(text) {
  var spacedString = '';
  var max = text.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    spacedString += text[i];
    if (i !== (max - 1)) {
      spacedString += ' ';
    }
  }
  return spacedString;
};

if (explode('Kristopher') === 'K r i s t o p h e r') {

  console.log('Success!');

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are looking for prototype extension, which I think is a bad idea. You should stick to define method.

However, as a solution. You need to pollute the existing `String` object.

```js
String.prototype.explode = function() {
  return this.split('').join(' '); //Improved code for explosion
};

if ('Kristopher'.explode() === 'K r i s t o p h e r') {
  console.log('Success!');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `explode` method to the `String` object:

```js
String.prototype.explode = function () {
  return this.split('').join(' ');
}

console.log('Kristopher'.explode());

if ('Kristopher'.explode() === 'K r i s t o p h e r') {
  console.log('Success!');
};
```